# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/C:/ci/astroid_1592481955828/work'

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to push a little python project to Heroku and I keep getting this error anytime I run `git push heroku master`

```
$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 19, done.
Counting objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 4.27 KiB | 728.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 19 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.10
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Processing /C:/ci/astroid_1592481955828/work
remote:        ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/C:/ci/astroid_1592481955828/work'
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to flask-plan-app.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/flask-plan-app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/flask-plan-app.git'
```

I have also tried locating the missing files on my laptop but I couldn't, please how do I fix this?

This is my requirement.txt file

```
astroid @ file:C:/ci/astroid_1592481955828/work
certifi==2020.6.20
click==7.1.2
colorama==0.4.3
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.3
gunicorn==20.0.4
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
pylint @ file:///C:/ci/pylint_1592487534522/work
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.18
toml @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/toml_1592853716807/work
typed-ast==1.4.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wincertstore==0.2
wrapt==1.11.2
```

Comment: Does this path look legit to you `'/C:/ci/astroid_1592481955828/work'`?

Comment: It doesn't, how do I change the path, or even what is the right path?

Comment: Is this path anywhere in your project? Just by looking at it, it seems like there's a very unnecessary `/` at the atart.

Comment: It's not anywhere in the project. But I have a file in my requirement.txt file pointing to that path

Comment: I just edited and added requirement.txt file in the question

Comment: This line `astroid @ file:///C:/ci/astroid_1592481955828/work` should be the same as other paths in the file.

Comment: Even the other paths doesn't exist

Answer (score 12):

I'm a beginner so take this with a grain of salt.

I deleted all the "@ paths" suffixes in the requirements file and just left the names of the packages, this stopped this error from happening.

So:

```
astroid 
certifi==2020.6.20
click==7.1.2
colorama==0.4.3
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.3
gunicorn==20.0.4
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
pylint 
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.18
toml 
typed-ast==1.4.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wincertstore==0.2
wrapt==1.11.2
```

Comment: seems when heroku tries to install requirements.txt file it also hits that path.

i dont know if there's a way to edit it from my folders

Comment: That just worked for me.. amazing this isn't better documented, just lost lots of time troubleshooting this

Answer (score 2):

Hi I just ran into this issue and was able to solve it. Posting in case any one runs into the same issue in the future.

Follow @extracheez's instructions of removing the surplus @ paths. Then make sure you commit and push to Git after. That solved it for me.

```
git add -A
git commit -m "removed surplus @ paths in requirements.txt file"
git push -u origin master
```

Another error might pop up though, something like `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_51de3815/static'`.

To solve that, create a `.temporary_file` file in your static folder. Something to do with Git not tracking empty directories, ergo it doesn't exist on Heroku.

```
touch static/.keep
```